# How to self-learn automated theorem proving?

Tags: automated-theorem-proving

Year 12 high school student here, but my ambition is set on Automated Theorem Proving. I wish to apply it to, of course, mathematics and computer science, and maybe if possible other applied subjects like physics, chemistry or even analytic philosophy.

I have yet to go to university to do a bachelor degree in Computer Science, but I would like to know what steps should I take to teach myself Automated Theorem Proving. Advice and tips from the ATP experts and what online resources and books are there available, etc. And how should I actually practice and do it? Also, should I jump straight to ATP or learn Computer Science in general first?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Unfortunately, your question is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. We prefer questions that have objectively correct answers that will be useful both to the asker and others who have the same question in the future. What is or is not a suitable topic for study, projects or research is very much a matter of opinion and depends crucially on the interests and skills of the person who will be doing the work and the support that will be available to them. This is a question that you should be asking your professors.